# Act with Flags and Reviews in one single post

Tags: discussion, support

When reviewing a Low Quality Post, appeared a [post that is not an answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/27174/27189) but a thank you comment.

Considering my all my possible actions, I could at least

- "Recommend Deletion" right away and this would count as +1 in LQP review (this number is relevant for badges)
- Open the post and flad it as "Not an answer".

I knew, from previous experience,that if a flag is the first action, then one can still review afterwards. This way I can see an increase in both actions and the post is still dealt with faster. Other way around I'm not so sure (flags can then be blocked because we already acted upon the post), so order here appears to be relevant (if you know order isn't relevant, you can let me know).

From my perspective, the only difference is that i get +1 for LQP reviews and +1 for raised flags and the post might even get attention faster and disappear.

Is that something this community is ok with? What's the impact this has on others? (apart from me getting badges faster and *maybe* more people having to deal with the post)